# Using Posit Cloud to access a locally installed SQL Server database

Tags: r, cloud

When running this code...

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                 Driver = "SQLServer",
                 Server = "DESKTOP-XXXX\\SQLEXPRESS", 
                 Port = "1433", 
                 UID = "publicaccess", 
                 PWD = "password", 
                 Database = "crime_camera", 
                 timeout = 10)
```

... in RStudio, within Posit Cloud, I get this message...

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1135: 00000: [RStudio][SqlServer] Failed to locate Server/Instance Specified.
```

I suspect the Cloud is unable to see my locally (my laptop) installed database.

If your SQL Server instance (where Server = "DESKTOP-XXXX\SQLEXPRESS") is running on your local machine, will the Posit Cloud environment be able to access it directly using that name? If not, how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It is not realistic to expect that posit:cloud can access resources on your local computer. In fact, if that were possible, that would be a significant security concern, having anybody who can see posit:cloud given carte-blanche access to (at a minimum) a database server on your local machine. Risky to say the least. Even if you are not concerned about opening your personal computer to the world, availability would be a concern ... if your laptop hibernates, your app dies. No, you should not attempt to access your local SQL Server instance from the internet.

Comment: Further, assuming that you are actually okay with this security risk, then ... your computer is not known to the universe as `DESKTOP-XXXX`. It is known by either an ip address (ip4 or ip6) or a fully-qualified name, such as `host146.pa.verizoncustomers.net` (completely made-up). And unless you are explicitly paying extra to your ISP, that can change based on events out of your control.

Comment: Ultimately, assuming (could easily go wrong here) that this is a small project, you have a few quick options: (1) set up an external data source in posit:cloud, see https://posit.cloud/learn/guide#external-data; (2) really, if you want your personal computer to be accessible, find your real IP address, read https://posit.cloud/learn/guide#firewall, and hope your OS is secure and up-to-date; (3) convert from SQL server to a file-based such as `duckdb` or `RSQLite`; (4) set up an AWS/GCP/... (outside of posit:cloud) and find the way to connect to it.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks, this is very helpful information.